# How can I import a dataframe from another script

Tags: python, python-import

I have a little beginner issue doing imports between scripts, maybe someone can help?

I wrote 2 Modules:

**- B01_Import_CSV_V1.py**

In the import script, i did load a .csv and saved it as a pandas dataframe (named "df").

```
import pandas as pd
global df
global df2


   

    
#%% load file via static path

if True:

   
    
    
    tester=r'C:\local_calc\Python_DemoFiles\20220219_70788_406_02_C10_275C_Ges.csv'
    df=pd.read_csv(tester, sep=';',decimal=",", skipfooter=1300, engine='python')
    
    
    
    
    print ('FINISHED loading file        ' + tester)
```

**- plot.py**

The plot script should process this data.

```
#%% Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import B01_Import_CSV_V1       #<- this works
#from B01_Import_CSV_V1 import df    #<- this does not work







#%%% plot
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax3=ax.twinx()
ax.plot( df['70788.1.E602000_W1:6'], c = 'b')
```

My questions:
It will only work, if i use the code "import B01_Import_CSV_V1" in the first script.

If I use "from B01_Import_CSV_V1 import df", it won't.
-> Why is that?

If I integrate the code of Import-Script in a main function (if **name**=="**main**":  ), i learned that this code won´t be executed anymore while import.
The plot script won´t work either then.
-> Does this mean, I have to execute the csv-Import within the plot script?

Is there any way to execute scripts separately and then use the variables from each other?

Comment: I don't quite see the point. The `import` in `plot.py` runs your `B01_Import_CSV_V1.py` script. So you could just as well do it all in `plot.py`. If you need to do some preprocessing of the data, you could just store the dataframe as a new CSV-file and read that into a dataframe in `plot.py`?

Comment: indeed, the structure with 2 scripts has no advantages YET.   but it will have some, as my code will grow.  Also, understanding what´s going on here will help me improve my skills ;)

Comment: Your original `from` statement will work just fine.  Why do you think it doesn't?  Also note that `global` is only used inside functions, and globals are local to the file they are contained in.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and import that in the other file:

```
import pandas as pd

def load_df():
    tester=r'C:\local_calc\Python_DemoFiles\20220219_70788_406_02_C10_275C_Ges.csv'
    df=pd.read_csv(tester, sep=';',decimal=",", skipfooter=1300, engine='python')
    print ('FINISHED loading file        ' + tester)
    return df
```

Then use in the other:

```
from B01_Import_CSV_V1 import load_df
df = load_df()
```